# Display content outside his own div in small screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries, background-image

I am using a background size cover for an image I want to display in my homepage full screen when you enter the site.

```
.image1{
    background: url(../img/nike.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 10px 60px 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

However, since the image is really wide, I want it to be all in the screen when you enter the site with a phone. That´s why I have used the following media query:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
                        .image1{
                            width:70%;
                            background-size: contain;
                        }
                    }
```

That is working and now you can still see the full image in mobile screens. But obviously it is not filling all the background. It has white space above and below it. So what I want is the text and logo I am going to put to appear in the white space above the image, and not in small size inside the image. I don´t know how to do this since the text and content I am placing is originally inside the div with this image as a background.

The only solution I can think about is to set the margin-top in the media query to -200px but I don´t think this is a very good practice.

You can see the site live in www.text.hdeprada.com It is a simple page with just this issue I am trying to fix.

Comment: I think your link is not working to the live website

Answer (score 0):

use backstretch js , it will resolve your problem. Its easy and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling the image inside the div with this

```
background-size:200%;
```

scale the % to fit your need